# Error when using Contains within linq query with results from another query

Tags: c#, linq

In the first query, I query list of steps for an ID. In the next query I check to see if that query contains an ID from new Query and C_S_Is_Button. But I get this error below. I have seen similar issues on this site but I havent figured out how to implement a solution into my problem.

Error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

First Query

```
var QcheckA = from csd in l.LCSDatas
                join cls in l.LCSteps on csd.C_S_ID equals cls.C_S_ID
                join cde in lol.LCDefinitions on csd.C_S_ID equals cde.C_S_ID
                where csd.A_ID == _AID && cde.C_ID == data.C_ID
                select new 
                {
                    csd.C_S_ID
                };
```

C Step. Find lowest step where button hasnt been clicked.

```
var QSID = (from cd in l.LCDefinitions
               join cs in l.LCSteps on cd.C_S_ID equals cs.C_S_ID                           
               where cs.C_S_Is_Button == true
                  && cd.C_ID == data.C_ID                              
                  && !QcheckA.Contains(cd.C_S_ID) //Error Here
               orderby cd.C_S_Order ascending
               select new
               {
                   cd.C_S_ID
               }).Take(1);

var SID = QSID.SingleOrDefault();
```

Any suggestions for this situtation? Thanks

Comment: Got to be some of the most unhelpful variable names of all time

Comment: Yeah I changed them to post it here. In main code it has better Variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous type in the first query and then in the second query you are trying to essentially compare an anonymous class type to a base type like an `int` or a `Guid`.

In your first query try to be more explicit (cast it to the exact type it is, I'm assuming `int` but you might be using a `Guid`):

```
select new  
{ 
    ID = (int)csd.C_S_ID 
};
```

Then, in your second query, create another anonymous type that is like the first being explicit on what type of property it contains:

```
&& !QcheckA.Contains(new { ID = (int)cd.C_S_ID} )
```

Comment: The error message went away so now I just need to test. Thanks for the help.